# How to join two CGAL::Point_set_3 without duplicate

Tags: cgal

I have many CGAL::Point_set_3, is there a quick way to write them into one ply file?

What I do currently is to join them together using Point_set_3::join(), then use CGAL::write_ply_points(). But it copies all entries and takes a lot of time.

Any way to avoid the copy of entries?

Thanks.

See a code example below

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Point_set_3<Point_3> Point_set;

Point_set ps1, ps2;
// insert points
ps1 += ps2 // merge point_set, duplicate happens here
CGAL::write_ply_points(...); // write ply to disk
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that illustrates the problem. Also use correct formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. Create a std::vector< std::pair< Point_3, Vector_3 > >;
2. Iterator over each point_set, push_back point and normal using std::move;
3. write to ply file using created vector.

Answer (score 0):

The function `write_ply_points()`  writes into a stream.  So you can call it several times with different point sets.

Comment: There is a header in the ply file, append its content one by one does not work.